# Thickbox iFrame Showing One Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thickbox

Is there away with using Thickbox that when I use an iFrame that I can only show one particular div instead of loading the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because you can't change anything on iFrames.
You can't just hide something on other pages.